# Dividing work to more threads takes more time, why?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pthreads, multiprocessing

I have a small C program which calculates *pi* using a [monte-carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Introduction)-simulation which basically just tests for a random point [x,y] if it's inside or outside a circle.

To approximate *pi* I have to use a high number of samples *n* which has a direct proportional complexity of *O(n)*. So trying to calculate a huge number of samples n, I implemented [POSIX threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) api to parallize the computational power.

My code looks like this:

```
pthread_t worker[nthreads]; /* creates workers for each thread */
struct param aparam[nthreads]; /* struct param{ long* hits; long rounds; }; */
long nrounds = nsamples / nthreads; /* divide samples to subsets of equal rounds per thread */

for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) { /* loop to create threads */
    aparam[i].hits = 0;
    aparam[i].rounds = nrounds;
    pthread_create(&worker[i], NULL, calc_pi, &aparam[i]); /* calls calc_pi(void* vparam){}  */ 
}

long nhits = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < nthreads; ++j) { /* collects results */
    pthread_join(worker[j], NULL);
    nhits += (long)aparam[j].hits; /* counts hits inside the cicrle */
}
```

And this is what each thread is doing:

```
void* calc_pi(void* vparam)
{ /* counts hits inside a circle */
    struct param *iparam;
    iparam = (struct param *) vparam;
    long hits = 0;
    float x, y, z;
    for (long i = 0; i < iparam->rounds; ++i) {
        x = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x * x + y * y;
        if (z <= 1.f) /* circle radius of 1 */
            ++hits;
    }
    iparam->hits = (long*)hits;
    return NULL;
}
```

Now I have a strange observation. With the same set of samples *n* and with an increasing number of threads *i* this program takes **more time instead of less**.

Here are some average run times (reproducable):

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Threads[1] | Samples[1] | Rounds[1] | Time[s] |
-------------------------------------------------
|        32  |  268435456 |   8388608 |    118  |
|        16  |  268435456 |  16777216 |    106  |
|         8  |  268435456 |  33554432 |    125  |
|         4  |  268435456 |  67108864 |    152  |
|         2  |  268435456 | 134217728 |     36  |
|         1  |  268435456 | 268435456 |     15  |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Why is for instance two threads doing the same work taking more than double of the time than one single thread? My assumption is that two threads dividing the work should reduce the time by at least 50%.

Compiled with GCC 4.9.1 and the following flags:

```
gcc -O2 -std=gnu11 -pthread pipa.c -lpthread -o pipa
```

My hardware is a Dual Intel Xeon E5520 (2 processors with each 4 cores) @ 2.26 GHz, hyperthreading disabled, running scientific linux with 2.6.18 kernel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Linux 2.6.18 is ancient. Like, prehistoric. I'm pretty sure there were a lot of improvements for multi-threaded programs since then. For example, which pthreads-implementation are you using? LinuxThreads or NPTL?

Comment: Are you sure that threads a running on different cores? Maybe for some reason they are sharing the same core, so the context switches overhead increases the runtime

Comment: rand() could be causing contention.

Comment: EOF, I can reproduce this on linux 3.17.3; Eric, I checked with htop and the threads are using all cores. 2501, rand() seems to be the problem, using rand_r() improves performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most expensive operation your thread performs is calling `rand()`. The `rand()` is a naive, simplistic, and generally non-MT scalable function (since it guarantees for the same seed to produce the same sequence of *random* numbers). I think the lock inside the `rand()` is serializing all the threads.(*)

A simple trick to confirm whether it is the problem or not, is to start the program under debugger, then, several times: pause it, capture the stack trace of the threads, continue. Whatever appears most often in the stacktraces, very likely is the bottleneck.

(*) What makes it even slower is the fact that lock contention causes additional performance penalty. Also, the many threads add additional overhead of the process scheduling and the context switches.