# Slow pthreads, does not appear to be mere overhead

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I've been trying to figure out why my program that approximates pi with Monte Carlo integration is running much slower with pthreads then single threaded both written in C. I have tested this on two different machines, both running the same OS but different hardware, and the results are almost identical.

First some information about my machines:

```
$ uname -rv                                                                                                                                                                                        
3.19.3-3-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 14:10:00 CEST 2015

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20150304 (prerelease)

$ pacman -Q |grep gcc
gcc-fortran 4.9.2-4
gcc-libs-multilib 4.9.2-4
gcc-multilib 4.9.2-4 
lib32-gcc-libs 4.9.2-4
```

Laptop: Sager NP7358 (CPU: i7-4710)

Desktop: Franken'puter (CPU: i7-4930k)

At first I came across [C++ Pthreads - Multithreading slower than single-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436001/c-pthreads-multithreading-slower-than-single-threading) for which the answer was that the creation of threads slows things down. This does not seem to be the issue for me. The single threaded program takes 3.57 seconds, a 6-threaded program takes 51 seconds and a 12 threaded program takes 1 minute 6 seconds. If creating the threads was the only issue I would except the difference to be greater. Also, with 24 threads it takes 1 minute 10 seconds, though this could be as a result of threads being reused instead instead of created. These results are for my desktop which has six cores and hyperthreading. On my laptop with four cores and hyperthreading the results are similar.

Furthermore, I found that by double the amount of work done within each thread, more than doubles the execution time on my desktop. However on my laptop the time scales as expected. Perhaps this is due to a difference in architecture? Ivybridge vs Haswell?

According to Htop, the correct number of logical cores are in use, and they are maxed out.

I'm compiling all threaded code with "gcc -o mcpi_pthread mcpi_pthread.c -pthread" and all single threaded code with "gcc -o mcpi_nothread mcpi_nothread.c". You'll see variables n and M. The reason I have both of those is that at first I wasn't sure if they needed to be equal. It turns out they do, or the code segfaults.

First the threaded version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int sum=0;

double frand() //why do I need this?
{
    double RandomDouble = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return RandomDouble;
}

int sample ()
/* This program is meant to generate a random x and a random y and check if 
 * $sqrt{1-x^2}<y$ */
{
    double x = frand();
    double y = frand();
    if( y*y + x*x >  1 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void *mcpi_routine(void *args); /*declare the routine, even if you
                                 */ don't define it

int main ()
/* Now we loop over N sample points to count how many times sample()
 * comes up 1 then divide by N to get an approximation of pi/4
 */
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    long N =8000000 ,M=8 ,n=8;
    double pi;
    long i;
    pthread_t threads[n]; //these are our threads
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,mcpi_routine,(void *) &N);
    }
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    pi = (double) 4.0 * sum/ (M*N);

    printf("Pi is aproximately equal to %f.4 .\n",pi);
    return 0;
}

void *mcpi_routine (void *args ) //need to create a routine
{
    int c=0,i;
    long *N = (long*) args;
    for(i=0;i<*N;i++)
    {
        c += sample();
    }
    sum += c;   
    return 0;
}
```

Now the single threaded

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

//int RAND_MAX = pow(2,16)-1;

double frand() //why do I need this?
{
    double RandomDouble = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return RandomDouble;
}

//double frand();

int sample ()
/* This program is meant to generate a random x and a random y and check if 
 * $sqrt{1-x^2}<y$ */
{
//  srand(time(NULL));
    double x = frand();
    double y = frand();
    if( y*y + x*x >  1 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

main ()
/* Now we loop over N sample points to count how many times sample() comes up 1
 * then divide by N to get an aproximation of pi/4 */
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int count=0,i;
    long N = 6*100000000;
    double pi;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        count += sample();
    }
    pi = 4.0 * count / N;
    printf("Pi is aproximately equal to %f.4 .\n",pi);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware that the number of sample points used differ between the two, because I was playing around with the threaded version trying to figure out why it wasn't working right. When I was actually comparing them, however, I made sure that the number of threads times the number points computed per thread was the same for both.

[edit] I didn't see this thread when I did my initial search 2 weeks ago, nor when I ran it again be fore posting, but it seems to be the exact same problem. I saw it to the side of my thread. [Dividing work to more threads takes more time, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076647/dividing-work-to-more-threads-takes-more-time-why?rq=1)

The answer there is that rand() is serializing threads since they share the same seed, or something like that. So it isn't the thread creation, but rather the rand() function. I'm not sure if this is the answer, but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: unrelated to the performance issue, but you need a lock to protect the shared variable `sum` in the multithreaded version (or use atomic increments)

Comment: I thought of that as well, however that would only be a problem if two threads tried to write to sum at the same time, which is sufficiently improbable that I didn't bother with mutex.

Comment: 'sufficiently improbable that I didn't bother' ... Please never work on any software I ever use :)  Seriously though, this attitude to coding will get you hurt.  Do it right or spend months debugging something that shouldn't ever happen...

Comment: `Concurrency bugs manifest only under specific
interleavings...As a result, many concurrency bugs slip into production runs and
manifest at user sites as failures. They have led to software failures that caused real-world disasters before.`[1](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~aliang/RS.pdf)[2](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi12/osdi12-final-103.pdf) See [Therac-25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25) for instance.

Comment: If you are unconcerned with the atomicity of `sum`, at least access it with `memory_order_relaxed` atomic loads/stores. Undefined behaviour is no joke.

Comment: If this was something that I was putting into production, I assure you I would make sure to lock my variables, however this is a toy problem, and it was not returning errors unless I had the thread count ridiculously high. I suspect those issues were caused by the lack of locking since as the threads get more numerous, and execution takes less time the chances of an issue increases.

You're right, Micheal, that is a terrible attitude. Laziness is in general bad. If this was for a job, something you might use, I would not cut corners.

Comment: All your threads are fighting over the same resource.

Comment: David, are you referring to the seed, or something else I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand()` "[is not reentrant or thread safe](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r)".

Your threads are likely contending on something internal to `rand()`.

Replace `rand()` with `rand_r()`.

Answer (score 0):

### Splitting up the work

The biggest problem with your code is that you aren't splitting up the work among your threads, **you are creating more work**.

For example, with 1 thread, you are doing 8000000 iterations.  With 20 threads, you are doing 8000000 **per thread**.  So if you have 4 cores, the best you can hope for in perfect conditions is that your threaded program will take 5 times longer than the single threaded one.  But you did 20 times the work!

What you need to do is in your `main()`:

```
long N = 6*100000000;

...

N /= M;  // Where M is the number of threads.
```

When I did this, I was able to run the threaded program in 1/4 the time of the single threaded program (I have 4 cores).

### Random numbers

A second problem is that you should use `rand_r()` instead of `rand()`.  Changing this does *not* speed up the running time. It will however, give you better results because if you use `rand()`, you will get duplicate random numbers in the threads that are calling it at the same time.

### Storing the sum safely

You shouldn't be adding to `sum` from each thread.  If two threads do this simultaneously you could lose one of your sums.  There are two easy ways to fix this:

1. Make `sum` be an array of size `M`.  Then pass into each thread its index and have it store its value into `sum[index]`.
2. Return `sum` from the thread function and have the `main` function read it when it calls `pthread_join()`.